# Solspace Super Search - Special Characters

Tags: solspace, supersearch

How can we make sure that special characters like ä,ö,å would be noticed while searching for content on a webpage. We are getting no results at the moment. I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm the dev of Low Search.

If you look at [the comparison table](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/super-search#compare) (which I helped set up together with the Solspace team), then you'll see that "Accent-insensitive (diacritics)" -- the special characters you're referring to -- is not supported by Super Search. As far as I'm aware, [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) is the only search solution in EE that allows for this functionality.